# How to integrate MATLAB in to C#?

Tags: c#, matlab, matlab-deployment, system-integration

I have UIs implemented using C#.NET and image processing procedure developed in MATLAB..Hence I need to know a way of integrating MATLAB into C#.NET to use these two processes as one system.....

Comment: Is this what you looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434331/interoperating-between-matlab-and-c

Answer (score 0):

Matlab Builder? http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/netbuilder/

Answer (score 0):

How to call user-defined matlab functions from within C#/.NET:

I explained it once [here](http://forum.finaquant.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1217) in detail. For this integration method you will need the **Deployment Tool** of matlab in order to compile your matlab functions into dll assemblies that can be referenced by C#/.NET.

To summarize, these are the steps:

1) Write your matlab functions (m files) and save them. You will call these functions from C#/.NET

2) Open *Deployment Tool* (deploytool) in matlab and add all the matlab m files to the package, named for example *MyMatlabFunctions.prj*

3) Add a class to deploy package with a name like *MyMatlabClass*. This class will contain the .NET translations (or compilations) of your matlab functions.

4) Build the package *MyMatlabFunctions.prj* with deploytool. The generated *MyMatlabFunctions.dll* will be referenced in our Visual Studio project.

5) Add matlab-related references (dll's) *MatCode.dll* and *MWarray.dll* to your Visual Studio project.

6) Write the C#/.NET method which calls the dll translation of your matlab functions. A simple example below: Matrix Addition (addMatrices.m)

```
static public void SimpleMatrixAddition()
{
    double[,] a = { { 2, 3 }, { 5, 6 }, { 8, 9 } }; //Matrix 1
    double[,] b = { { 1, 2}, { 4, 5}, { 7, 8} };    //Matrix 2

    MWNumericArray arr1 = a;
    MWNumericArray arr2 = b;

    MyMatClass obj = new MyMatClass();

    // call matlab function (addMatrices.m)
    MWArray result = (MWNumericArray)obj.addMatrices((MWArray)arr1, (MWArray)arr2);

    // display matlab matrix
    Console.WriteLine("matlab matrix:\n" + result);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```