# Accessing a common memory (containing images) from dotnet and matlab simultaneously

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

Does we have a common memory space where images can be stored which can be accessed by both dotnet and matlab at same time. Whereas we want to store images to a common memory from matlab code. And also we want to retrieve the images from that memory space through the dotnet code.
It is appreciable if you can suggest the efficient memory utilization which we can adopt?

Comment: no. some words to pass limit

Comment: No, but you can [interoperate between .NET and Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/a/435654/69809), i.e. call .NET libraries from Matlab or expose Matlab scripts as .NET libraries.

Comment: I think the simplest way is to save the image into file on memory drive (google for RAM drive). Another way is to create memory share manager dll.