# How to read c# through Matlab

Tags: c#, matlab

I have a program in c# and I would like to have the program exactly the same but in matlab, is there a way that matlab can read the whole c# program or do I need to rewrite everything in matlab?

thanks,

Comment: Possibly related: [Interoperating between Matlab and C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/434331/5358968)

Comment: I will have a look thanks loops helpfull